# Highcharts exportchart PDF not showing all categories

Tags: javascript, pdf, highcharts

I am in process of verifying the categories on exported PDF as compared to displayed chart in my setup. But, always i see some category names are missing in exported chart.

How can i make xAxis categories to empty, i mean exported PDF does not contains categories as Jan, Feb etc... in the exported PDF. I have a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/p9nt0he9/

```
 $(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Exports a pdf with name: my-pdf'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }],

    navigation: {
        buttonOptions: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
});

// the button handler
$('#button').click(function () {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.exportChart({
        type: 'application/pdf',
        filename: 'my-pdf',
        xAxis: [],
    });
});
```

});

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use exporting/chartOptions and there in xAxis/labels return empty string in formatter.

```
exporting:{
        chartOptions:{
            xAxis:[{
                labels:{
                    formatter:function(){
                        return '';
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/p9nt0he9/1/

Docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.chartOptions

Comment: See this http://jsfiddle.net/p9nt0he9/2/, my problem is, when i download the PDF some of the categories on axis are missing when have big array of categories on bar chart. For example.. in PDF, it only export categories jan, mar, may, july. etc In the given fiddle it is exporting fine and this problem i am facing in my development environment only. I see this happens only on certain occasions only based on categories array values. Can i have all categories printed correctly in PDF?

Comment: Could you replicate categories which are not exported? Have you tried to export unworkign demo with our exporting tool, not your own?